# Java: File[] to JTable

Tags: java, swing, file, directory

I am creating a musicplayer that has a table showing songs from a folder (like a playlist).
My problem is that the next row being added has the same result (name) as the previous one.

In my folder "tracks" there is track1, track2, track 3.
If I use:

```
File tracksFolder = new File("tracks");
final File[] tracks = tracksFolder.listFiles();

Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();

for (int i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(tracks[i]);
    row.add(tracks[i].toString());
    data.add(row);
}

Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();
headers.add("Song");

final JTable table = new JTable( data, headers );
// some more code
```

It returns in console:

```
tracks/track 1.wav
tracks/track 2.mp3
tracks/track 3.flac
```

but my table:

```
tracks/track 1.wav
tracks/track 1.wav
tracks/track 1.wav
```

The weirdest thing is that it works in my console!

Comment: make debugger your friend. look  how many files you could see tracksFolder.listFiles()  returns?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I put: System.out.println(tracksFolder.listFiles().toString()); and it gave me [Ljava.io.File;@d8f459 which is one line only.

Comment: Debugging allows you to go through step by step evaluation of your code.if you are using eclipse, click [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reuse your `row` vector object for every single row. You are just adding the entries to the already existing row; the renderer apparently shows the first entry of the `row` vector.

Solution: Move the creation of the row `Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();` inside the loop to create a new one for every row.

Or better, read about table models and use an appropriate one. It is in fact much less work once you understand the basics.